# Determining endianness of integers in array

Tags: c++, x86, number-formatting, endianness

My code is supposed to detect whether the integers stored in my array are in big endian or little endian order.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num[] = {0,0,0x04030201,0,0};

    //int num = 0x04030201;

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        if(*(char *)&num[i] == 1) {
            printf("\nLittle-Endian\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Big-Endian\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since my computer is intel, all the numbers should be stored in little endian. This means I expect the code to go through each integer in my array and print little endian, so it should just print little endian 5 times. But this is the output that I am currently getting:

```
Big-Endian
Big-Endian
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Only one of your array elements has `1` as the least-significant byte of the value.  The all-zero bytes of `(int)0`will of course not be `== 1`.

Comment: Also, `printf` is defined in `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`, not `<iostream>`

Comment: @PeterCordes So would I fix the conditional for my if statement in that case such that the 0 can be detected as little endian? How would you solve this?

Comment: Unless you already know the expected value of each element, the problem is insoluble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't test the endianness of arbitrary or unknown values**.  If all the bytes of an `int` are zero, it doesn't matter what order they're in.

---

Your code prints

```
Big-Endian
Big-Endian

Little-Endian
Big-Endian
Big-Endian
```

as expected on my x86-64 system, because your testing method is wrong.  Your question makes it sound like it *always* printed Big-Endian!

---

Only one of your array elements has `1` as the least-significant byte of the value. The all-zero bytes of `(int)0` will of course not be `== 1`.

You can't check endianness with a number where all the bytes have the same value, because regardless of endianness you'll load the same value.

The `== 1` check works for `0x04030201` because the low byte of that value is `1`.  It doesn't work in general.  You could equally do something like `== 0x88` in `0x4455667788` to see if the first byte in memory is the `0x88` byte.

(I'm saying "byte" instead of `char` because we're talking about x86-64, which does have 8-bit bytes, and all the mainstream C++ implementations use 1-byte `char` and 32-bit `int`.)

---

## How to fix it

Endianness is a property of the implementation for a certain target architecture, and can't be different for different array elements.

```
int  endian_test = 0x12345678;
char *p = (char*)&endian_test;

const char *endian_string = "unknown endian";
if (p[0] == 0x78 && p[1] == 0x56 && p[2] == 0x34 && p[3] = 0x12)
    endian_string = "Little-Endian";
if (p[3] == 0x78 && p[2] == 0x56 && p[1] == 0x34 && p[0] = 0x12)
    endian_string = "Big-Endian";
// test for PDP-endian if you want

for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    // It's guaranteed that all elements of the array have the same endianness as endian_test
    puts(endian_string);
}
```

Big and little aren't the only endiannesses possible.

Also note that you can and detect this with CPP macros.  [gcc at least provides macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) that let you do

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
 ...
#else
#endif
```

But these macros aren't ISO C++ standard.  The "runtime" check can optimize away to nothing (because the result is a compile-time constant true or false), but the preprocessor lets you disable code that wouldn't even compile.

In C++20, [use `std::endian`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) `type_traits`.

Comment: You mean I can jut look at a number and tell the endianness? (ducking..)

Comment: I tried the "== 0x88" instead of "== 1" and now it just prints all of it as Big-Endian. Can you clarify a bit further how I can do a more general check for little endianness that would also apply for the 0's in the array?

Comment: @T0ny50pr4n0: `== 0x88` only works when testing a value that's `== 0x88` when you cast it to `(char)` (i.e. when you take the least significant 8 bits of the value).